# Reducing vertices while not reducing quality

Tags: modeling, vertices, topology

This model now has 3,840 triangles I need to reduce it to 1,400 triangles but still keep it's good looks and smoothness. 
I have tried Limited Dissolve but it just creates bumps and messes up the vertices.
Does anyone have any suggestions?
Is there possibly a way to merge all the vertices into one line therefor reducing vertices?

Here is what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to add an image or two of your model?  That would really help in suggesting how to approach it.  Have you tried a Decimate modifier set to *Planar*?

Comment: Ok, I added a picture.

Comment: I already tried that :(

Comment: When reducing geometry you'll loose some quality anyway. You can reduce polycount either by editing actual mesh (e.g. removing loopcuts like in linked answer) or by creating another one atop of this one (retopologizing). You might want to bake the normal map from high poly to lowpoly after that in order to preserve some vision of details.